# Coffeescript running a second function before the first has finished executing

Tags: coffeescript, design-patterns

My code is as follows. I would expect the code inside `configureMission()` to finish running before running `mapSurface`. This does not appear to be happening.

```
missionCommands = "" # you don't have a mission yet
$('#startExploration').click -> # Set #missionControl as input for game configuration
    configureMission()
    mapSurface()        

configureMission =-> 
   $('#MissionControl').on "submit", ->
      # cool helper function shamelessly pinched from http://jsfiddle.net/sxGtM/3/
      $.fn.serializeObject = function() # not shown

      missionCommands = JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject())
      return false #stops click event from firing

 mapSurface =->
    console.log('map')
    console.log(missionCommands)
```

I have noticed that if I submit the form a second time, the `missionCommands` variable has been updated with the json data, so it appears that the form data has been processed, but that this is happening after the second function has run.

```
map login.js:60
   login.js:61
map login.js:60
{"xMaximum":"","yMaximum":"","xCoord":["iuoiuyi",""],"yCoord":["",""],"orientaiton":["",""]} login.js:61
```

I can make it work by moving the `mapSurface`  function inside the `configureMission` function, but this seems like bad form. I wonder, is there a more correct pattern I could use to achieve my desired result of processing the form data into json, setting this into a variable and passing the variable to a second function.

Comment: @Hiroto thanks for the grammar heads up. It's quite late : )

Comment: `configureMission` just binds a submit handler (a new one every time it is called). So it will run but there won't be any visible effect until there is a submit. What am I missing?

Comment: @muistooshort I used .on in place of .live (not tested this yet) because the form will be manipulated by DOM prior to submission. ?? The required functionality is that the click event is tied to the form input, the user inputs the information for the 'mission' and when the form is submitted this mission data will then be animated in a canvas element to plot a course. I need to use the jsonified data from the `configureMission` function in the `mapSurface` function and beyond, and I need the 'submit' event to both process the form data and display it on the page. Does that make sense?

Comment: The problem is that `configureMission` **does not** do anything with the JSON, it simply binds a submit that will build `missionCommands`. The order will be something like `configureMission()`, `mapSurface()`, time passes, the submit handler gets called.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Any suggestions as to what I **should** do with with the JSON? to give you some context I'm using it within a backbone view on a rails app. I don't need to pass it around, I just want to generate a graph on a canvas element next to the form.

Comment: Maybe find the submit handler exactly once and then push the `mapSurface` call into the submit handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're treating asynchronous commands as synchronous commands. JavaScript (and thereby CoffeeScript) works asynchronously, meaning that functions will be run in parallel.

You can solve this problem by specifying `mapSurface()` as the callback for `configureMission()` as follows:

```
missionCommands = ""
$('#startExploration').click ->
    configureMission(mapSurface)

configureMission = (cb) -> 
   console.log "now running configureMission()"
   $('#MissionControl').on "submit", ->
      $.fn.serializeObject = function() # not shown

      missionCommands = JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject())
      console.log "completed configureMission()"
      return cb()

mapSurface = ->
   console.log "now running mapSurface()"
   console.log missionCommands
   console.log "completed mapSurface()"
```

Learn about JavaScript callbacks here: http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/.

Comment: nice, just what I needed to get my head round it. Thanks